# Cannot resolve symbol 'github' in android

Tags: android, github

I am trying to import github in android development like below.

> import com.github.pires.obd.commands.protocol.EchoOffCommand;
> import com.github.pires.obd.enums.ObdProtocols;

But getting error message like **Cannot resolve symbol 'github'**

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }

}
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "sss.sss.obdapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
//noinspection OutdatedLibrary
implementation 'com.fazecast:jSerialComm:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible

}
```

Can you please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Add `implementation 'com.github.pires:obd-java-api:1.0'` in your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your `build.gradle` this dependency:

```
dependencies {
   //..
   implementation 'com.github.pires:obd-java-api:1.0'
}
```